# Diophantine Equation with 15th power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

So I'm working on the Diophantine equation $2x^2-1=y^{15}$ (1) with $x,y>1$

In particular I want to show that x must be a multiple of 5.  I have found that it suffices to show that for $y=1 \pmod{10}$ (1) can't have a solution, but I'm stuck.

Also (I don't know if this helps) $y^{15}+1$ can be written as $(y^5+1)(y^2-y+1)(y^8+y^7-y^5-y^4-y^3+y+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea.  Rewrite the equation as

$$16x^2=8y^{15}+8$$

and then let $v=4x$ and $u=2y^5$.  This turns things into an elliptic curve equation

$$v^2=u^3+8$$

which, if I recall correctly, can have at most finitely many integer solutions.  Not all integer solutions $(u,v)$ correspond to integer solutions $(x,y)$, but all integer solutions $(x,y)$ *do* correspond to integer solutions $(u,v)$.